# Natural params and sufficient statistics in multivariate normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution

Let's represent multivariate normal distribution as an exponential family:

\begin{align}
f_X( x | \Theta ) = h(x)g(\Theta)\exp( \eta(\Theta) \cdot T(x) )
\end{align}

Where natural parameters:

\begin{align}
\eta(\Theta) = \left[
\begin{matrix}
\Sigma^{-1} \mu \\
-\frac12 \Sigma^{-1}
\end{matrix}
\right]
\end{align}

Sufficient statistic:

\begin{align}
T(x) = \left[
\begin{matrix}
x \\
xx^T
\end{matrix}
\right]
\end{align}

Does $\eta(\Theta) \cdot T(x)$ denote a dot product?

If so then we can't get a scalar value. We need some more complex function then dot product - for instance trace: $\operatorname*{Tr}(\Sigma^{-1} xx^T) = \operatorname*{Tr}(x^T\Sigma^{-1} x)= x^T\Sigma^{-1} x$

Update

What are the proper identical transformations to get:

\begin{align}
\eta(\Theta) \cdot T(x) = \\
\left[
\begin{matrix}
\Sigma^{-1} \mu \\
-\frac12 \Sigma^{-1}
\end{matrix}
\right] \cdot \left[
\begin{matrix}
x \\
xx^T
\end{matrix}
\right] = \\
??? = \\
-\frac12 x^T \Sigma^{-1} x + \mu^T \Sigma^{-1} x
\end{align}

Comment: It took me a while to figure it out, but I wrote a full derivation [here](https://maurocamaraescudero.netlify.com/post/multivariate-normal-as-an-exponential-family-distribution/)

Comment: @Euler_Salter very helpful, thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

However, the inner product has an alternative form $x^T\Sigma x=\sum_{i,j} x_i x_j \sigma_{ij}$ where $\Sigma=\{\sigma_{ij}\}$.

Comment: I can't understand how to "insert" the $\Sigma^{-1}$ between two $x$s? What kind of operator should we use here? My guess is a trace operator ...

Hence, does $\eta(\Theta) \cdot T(x)$ denote any functon of $\Theta$ and $x$ ?

Comment: no you don't. We are trying to evaluate the bilinear form here $x^T \Sigma^{-1} x$. Expand the bilinear form term by term.

Comment: \begin{align}

\eta(\Theta) \cdot T(x) = \\
\left[
\begin{matrix}
\Sigma^{-1} \mu \\
-\frac12 \Sigma^{-1}
\end{matrix}
\right] \cdot \left[
\begin{matrix}
x \\
xx^T
\end{matrix}
\right] = \\
??? = \\
-\frac12 x^T \Sigma^{-1} x + \mu^T \Sigma^{-1} x
\end{align}